# changing style sheet of clicked menu item asp.net master page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have an asp.net master page with a menu like this:

```
 <menu id="menu">
    <nav id="main_nav">   
     <ul id="menu-primary">
      <li ><a href="./">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="staff.aspx">Staff</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sales</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Support</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Administration</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </menu>
```

In master page, I want to change css for the menu item clicked. I have this jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul li a').each(function () {
            var text_splited = $(this).text().split(" ");
            $(this).html("<span>" + text_splited.shift() + " " + text_splited.join(" ") + "</span> ");
        });

        // click on the first item on page load
        $('#menu-primary li').eq(0).click();

        $('#menu-primary li').click(function (e) {
            alert('here');
            // remove all active classes
            $('#menu-primary li').removeClass('current-menu-item');
            // add active class to clicked item
            $(this).addClass('current-menu-item');
        });
    });


</script>
```

Here is the css

```
nav#main_nav ul li.current-menu-item a,
nav#main_nav ul li a:hover {background: url("../images/menu_bg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 -149px transparent; border-bottom:1px solid #edf7ff}
nav#main_nav ul li.current-menu-item a span,
nav#main_nav ul li a:hover span{background: url("../images/menu_bg.png") no-repeat scroll 100% -118px transparent;}
```

This one works :

// click on the first item on page load
         $('#menu-primary li').eq(0).click();

```
     $('#menu-primary li').click(function (e) {
         // remove all active classes
         alert($('#menu-primary li').html());
         $('#menu-primary li').removeClass('current-menu-item');
         // add active class to clicked item
         $(this).addClass('current-menu-item');
         return false;
     });
```

But the page is not loaded because th efunction return false.

The alert is shown but the css is not applied to the clicked item.

Comment: That looks fine, are you sure you're styling `current-menu-item` in your CSS? A link to your page would be great.

Comment: @Abody97 yes I have current-menu-item in my css. Page is not online yet

Comment: Can you show us your CSS, please?

Comment: @Abody97 please check updated question with css

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing something like this

```
$("#menu-primary li.current-menu-item").removeClass("current-menu-item");
$(this).addClass("current-menu-item");
```

To set first menu item to be selected by default add `current-menu-item` class to it like this

```
<li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
```

**[See Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/8gz4k/)**

**Alternative approach based on Page URL**

```
$('#menu-primary li a').each(function() {
    var path = window.location.href;
    var current = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/'));
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    if(current=="")
    $('#menu-primary li a').first().addClass('current-menu-item');


        if (url == current) {

            $(this).addClass('current-menu-item');
    };
});
```

Comment: It is not working. also, I want first menu item selected by default

Comment: I added this edited li item. now first item is selected by default, but when i click any other menu item, it gets selected and then first item is selected as page loads on each menu item click

Comment: same thing. first item is selected I didnt add $("#menu-primary li.current-menu-item").removeClass("current-menu-item");
$(this).addClass("current-menu-item");

Comment: @DotnetSparrow Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle and reproduce the problem?

Comment: Try to nav#main_nav ul li.current-menu-item instead of applying the style to a

Comment: @freebird Please check updated question with return false, it works but page is not loaded

Comment: no, it is not working. selection changes page is not loaded because of return false.